# Cordova: Can we have same plugin with different versions inside different platform sections of config.xml?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

In a Cordova project - Can we have same plugin with different versions inside different platform sections of config.xml? Some like below,

```
<platform name="android">
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-some-plugin" spec="1.0.0" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-some-plugin" spec="2.0.0" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, since plugins are added with `cordova plugin add X` without a platform specification. Maybe someone can prove me wrong, but my suggestions would be to create 2 separate projects.